# Assert and then retract a class instance in OWLAPI

Tags: java, owl-api

I am asserting a new individual of a temporary class like follows:

```
OWLIndividual newRandomInstance = _owlDataFactory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(OntoStringIRI + "#random" + n));
OWLClass tempClass = _owlDataFactory.getOWLClass("pre:tempClass", _prefixManager);
OWLClassAssertionAxiom classAssertion = _owlDataFactory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(tempClass, newRandomInstance);
_manager.applyChange(new AddAxiom(_newOnto, classAssertion));
```

After running the reasoning engine this instance will also become an instance of an another class e.g. destClass. I need to remove the individual from being an individual of tempClass and retain the axiom for being an individual of destClass. I am trying with the removeAxiom clause like follows but it does not remove it from tempClass:

```
_manager.removeAxiom(_newOnto, classAssertion);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you building the reasoner? If you're using the standard construction, you'll get a buffering reasoner - it will not see changes in the ontology until you call the `flush()` method.

The axiom removal code you're using is correct.

Comment: It was the print class individuals method which "lied" to me about the class instances :)